# How can I use PHP Search with 2 Fields and get exact Match?

Tags: php

I have one searchform to search Firstname and lastname. Know I dont know how do I make it that I get exact results of both..

```
<form action="search1.php" method="GET">
<label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input type="name1" name="query" />
    <label for="lastname">lastname</label>
    <input type="lastname" name="query1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

Now in the Database guests I have name1 for firstname and lastname = lastname.
So when somebody searchs I want that it only Shows if both match.

My search1.php:

```html
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$query = $_GET['query1']; 
// gets value sent over search form
 
$min_length = 3;
// you can set minimum length of the query if you want
 
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then
     
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;
     
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection
     
    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guests WHERE name1 LIKE "$query" AND lastname LIKE "$query1";") or die(mysql_error());
        
  if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following
         
        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
         
            echo "<p><h3>".$results['title']."</h3>".$results['text']."</p>";
            // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
        }
         
    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }
     
}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
```

Would be very cool if someone can help me.. I know how make a search for 1 Input but not that 2 or 3 Inputs Need to match?

Comment: I think that is correct:
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guests WHERE name1 LIKE Field1 AND lastname LIKE field2;") or die(mysql_error());
I just have blockout.. but how I give field a Name on search1 now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="search1.php" method="GET">
<label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input type="name1" name="query" />
    <label for="lastname">lastname</label>
    <input type="lastname" name="query1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

My search1.php:

```
<?php
// gets value sent over search form
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$query1 = $_GET['query1'];

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;


    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guests WHERE name1 LIKE '".$query."' AND lastname LIKE '".$query1."' ") or die(mysql_error());


        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

            echo "<p><h3>".$results['title']."</h3>".$results['text']."</p>";
            // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
        }

    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }


}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
```

Comment: Works if you Change one more Thing:
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$query1 = $_GET['query1'];

Answer (score 0):

If u want to match both the fields of database exactly then you can do this

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guests WHERE name1='".$query."' AND lastname='".$query1."';") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Dosent work.. getting then ups Website not found if using mine Code and replace just the one with your. if i use the Code from @adern-nerk it works.. but getting no results even if the results are exact match in the database.